# webpack-dev-server can't find localhost

Tags: npm, localhost, webpack, mamp, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to get started with **React** using **webpack**, but keep running into an error when I try to set up **webpack-dev-server**. I ran

```
npm install webpack-dev-server
```

followed by

```
webpack-dev-server
```

and the command line returns the following:

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

Any clues on what is happening here?

I don't really know how webpack works to try and search for the root of the problem, but I've also been developing a website using PHP at port 80 with **MAMP**, I don't know if this is maybe part of the issue?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Solved, turned out my hosts file (found under /etc/hosts on a mac) had one line missing and so webpack couldn't find localhost. I restored it to its default following [these instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2014/04/12/restore-original-hosts-file-mac/) and it now works!

Comment: Great stuff. My hosts was empty - oddly webpack-dev-server was working, but 'electron-webpack dev' was not!

Comment: Same here, my hosts was also mysteriously empty!

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your /etc/hosts file includes localhost.

Open `/etc/hosts`

```
$ sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

Copy and paste this, if it's missing:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Answer (score 7):

The most common reason for that error is that you have something else already using that port. Try starting it on another port.

```
webpack-dev-server --port 3001
```

Comment: hey, i tried your suggestion but get the exact same error. is there another way to reconfigure it?

Comment: Yes, but it depends on how you have webpack setup. Start with the node server js file and look for app.listern, then either hard code a new port number or work your way back through the code to where it's configured.

Answer (score 7):

Did not work for me even after restoring the hosts file and trying with a different port. The way I made it to work was to give a custom host (127.0.0.1) and port (3001 or any other available) when starting the server:

```
webpack-dev-server --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3001
```

Answer (score 2):

Also check if /etc/hosts have 127.0.0.1 pointing to localhost as well.

Answer (score 1):

Also encountered the same error and nothing fixed it.

It appears, in my case, that I accidentally "corrupted" the `/etc/hosts` file by been able to write to it without the `sudo` permission.

The clue was when I `cat /etc/hosts` the output was one messy line. I deleted and re-created the file as `sudo`, with the @lizzie-cd link and all went back to normal

Answer (score 1):

In latest mac and linux os , the webpack dev server wokinnly only on adding the

```
host: "127.0.0.1"
```

inside the `devServer` in the `webpack.config`

Answer (score 0):

Hosts file was fine. Going into **web/dev.js** and updating the file to the following fixed this issue for me. Still not sure why.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const path = require('path');
const { buildConfig, APP_PATH, WEB_PATH } = require('./common');

module.exports = (env, argv) => (
  merge(buildConfig(env, argv), {
    entry: path.join(WEB_PATH, 'index.hmr.js'),
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],

    devServer: {
       contentBase: APP_PATH,
       openPage: '',
       inline: true,
       stats: 'minimal',
       open: true,
       port: 3001,
       hot: true,
       host: "127.0.0.1"
    },
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. I had explicitly add the dev server port to my hosts file. E.g.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost:8001
```

Then `npm run dev` works again.

If that still does not work for you you could try removing node_modules completely and re-installing fresh.

```bash
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install # Or `yarn`
```