# Vue CLI & Webpack: can't get webpack-dev-server to run

Tags: node.js, linux, webpack, vue.js, opensuse

i'm generating a webpack development server with `vue init webpack project-name`. after generating the server, running `npm run dev` produces the following error:

```
> client@1.0.0 dev /home/localhost/dev/vuetest/client
> webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

 10% building modules 1/3 modules 2 active .../client/index.js?http://localhost:8080events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:50:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1498:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:50:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/localhost/.npm/_logs/2018-06-17T22_25_08_212Z-debug.log
```

here's the dev script from `package.json`, autogenerated by vue

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js"
```

here's the versions of node and vue-cli i'm using:

```
$ node -v
v10.4.0
$ vue -V
3.0.0-rc.2
```

things i've tried so far:

- rolling back webpack-dev-server and webpack itself to prior versions
- checking all of my ports; i definitely have nothing running on :8080 and webpack is supposed to automatically seek a new port anyways. previous answers to this issue widely suggest that this is a port conflict issue, but that's not the case here.
- reinstalling vue-cli

interestingly, i get this error on both Windows 10 and openSUSE Tumbleweed (the current machine), but when i generate the same vue project on an Ubuntu VM, it works perfectly.

**EDIT:**

the problem was due to `webpack.dev.conf.js` attempting to use my linux `hostname` instead of the default "localhost". changing this line:

```
host: HOST || config.dev.host,
```

to this:

```
host: "localhost",
```

solved the issue.

Comment: could it be `localhost` not defined in your hosts file somehow?

Comment: if so, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757799/webpack-dev-server-cant-find-localhost

Comment: i don't think so - i should've also mentioned that vue-cli works perfectly with browserify. it's specifically related to webpack, as far as i can tell. EDIT: just tried out the recommended solution from this link and nothing has changed.

Comment: What happens if you run `ping localhost` in cmd or terminal?

Comment: you just helped me figure it out!! it wasn't actually trying to host it on localhost; it was trying to host it at my *hostname* in openSUSE. in my OP i censored my hostname with "localhost", thinking that the hostname variable and the localhost address were synonymous. i changed the host in the webpack dev configuration to "localhost" and it fixed everything.

Comment: @betweenvenus you should write that up as an answer. It's unlikely you'll be the only person running into this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating project with this. You use version 3 rc.2 and init command belongs to version 2.

```
vue create project-name
```

Docs:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#using-the-gui

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there were two solutions to this problem:

as @atilkan pointed out, the `vue init project-name` command has been deprecated as of Vue CLI 3. using `vue create project-name`, i've been able to successfully generate and run a development server. you can read more about Vue CLI 3's new project creation syntax [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html).

also, the project originally created by the deprecated `vue init` command was failing to assign itself the proper hostname. the problem was due to webpack.dev.conf.js attempting to use my linux hostname instead of the default "localhost". changing this line:

```
host: HOST || config.dev.host,
```

to this:

```
host: "localhost",
```

solved the issue. `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND yourHostName` errors may be fixable by doing this, though this is probably not the best method.