# I'm trying to figure out why "yarn start" command won't complete because of the error (as I understand, something with port)

Tags: node.js, port, node-modules, yarnpkg, npm-start

I'm trying to start my project by using these 2 basic scripts:

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --env.mode development --env.port 8080",
"build": "webpack --env.mode production".
```

Unfortunately, I keep on getting the next error:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1457:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:17)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

build script executes without any errors, but start one simply won't run. I've already tried switching ports, uninstalling node and installing it again (switched form LTS to the newest version and back), I've tried to kill all the processing running on 8080 post by using netstat, nothing helped.

If it helps, events.js lines where the execution stops are the next:

```
  events = target._events;
  if (events === undefined) {
    events = target._events = Object.create(null);
    target._eventsCount = 0;
  }// else {
    // To avoid recursion in the case that type === "newListener"! Before
    // adding it to the listeners, first emit "newListener".
   (LINE 173) if (events.newListener !== undefined) {
      target.emit('newListener', type,
                  listener.listener ? listener.listener : listener);

      // Re-assign `events` because a newListener handler could have caused the
      // this._events to be assigned to a new object
      events = target._events;
    }
    existing = events[type];
  }
```

Comment: Shot in the dark, but can you run `http-server` without issue?  [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757799/webpack-dev-server-cant-find-localhost) answer had issues with the hosts file.

Comment: @Phix thank you!!! You've literally saved me with that link, the problem was that my hosts file was empty and I had to simply rewrite it. Now webpack compiled successfully!

Comment: Great, good to know!