# GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26) error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

while running **yarn run develop** I am getting this error:::  webpack-dev-server --open --config ./webpack.config.develop.js Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND apps.local.clarivate.com     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26) **error Command failed with exit code 1**.

please someone help me

I am using node v10.16.0,yarn -- 1.22.4

Comment: I also added port in my hosts.txt file under C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc    127.0.0.1        apps.local.xyz.com

Comment: check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757799/webpack-dev-server-cant-find-localhost

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/whats-the-cause-of-the-error-getaddrinfo-eai-again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the cause of the error 'getaddrinfo EAI\_AGAIN'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182121/whats-the-cause-of-the-error-getaddrinfo-eai-again)